# Modificar reglas seguridad Firebase desde Android

Tags: firebase

Hola buenas estoy intentando hacer una app en la que un administrador concede privilegios a ciertos usuarios. Para ello los usuarios se registran en 
FireBase y con las reglas de seguridad de Firebase otorgo si pueden o no acceder a determinados nodos. El problema es que no se como modificar estas
reglas desde Android. Si alguien sabe de que otra forma podría hacerlo pero utilizando siempre FireBase que me lo diga. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Las reglas podrían ser nada más que un conjunto de "permisos" dentro de cada usuario. De esa manera el admin puede modificar esos permisos y dentro de las reglas de la BD puedes chequear que determinado usuario tenga un hijo X en el nodo de permisos.

Answer (score 0):

No deberias de hacerlo asi, para eso lo deberias hacer desde la pagina, pero lo que puedes hacer es que si quieres que un usuario en particular lea algun tipo de data puedes chequear un valor dentro del database y si existe hacer que el usuario lo lea, por ejemplo en rules en la parte de lectura pondrias una referencia

```
".read" : "root.child('groups').child($groupID).child(auth.userid).exists()"
```

entonces esto chequea que el usuario autenticado chequee por el valor dentro del hijo grupos, si este valor existe, entonces el usuario puede leerlo, de otra menera , si el valor no se encuentra, no podra leerlo.

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpt1F.png)

Hola tengo un problema parecido pero al añadir la regla me dice permiso denegado.

```
{"rules":{
    "Actividades": {
        ".read" : "data.child('Autor').val() == auth.uid",
            ".write" : "auth != null"        
        }
    }
}
```